# How to handle dynamic values in json request post body in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter searched a lot but unable to find solution.A little help is appreciated. Thanks.

Problem - 
In my http request I have below body 
My actual request is

```
{
  "Summary": {
    "source": {
      "Name": "Phones",
      "dataSource": "Oracle",
      "dbType": "${Value}",
      "sid": "${sUsername}",
      "spswd": "${sPassword}",
      "aut": "${win}",    
      "PrjName": "${sourceprojectName}"
    },
    "Destination": {
      "dataSource": "SQL",
      "projectName": "${destprojectName}",
      "server": "${urlValue}"
      "destUsrName": "${dUsername}",
      "destPswd": "${dPassword}",
    },
    "Notifiction": "True",
    "Time": "dd:mm:yy",
    "Config": true,
    "Properties": [
      {
        "type": "iPhone",
        "ids": [
          {
            "id": "f132d",
            "Guid_id": null
          },
          {
            "id": "6332569",
            "Guid_id": null
          },
          {
            "id": "5b55d2f",
            "Guid_id": null
          },
          {
            "id": "81f1330",
            "Guid_id": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "Execute": true
}
```

The id in the request is dynamic so I want to paramterize it.
using Json extractor I got these Id's from another response.
All these Id's are in array. `id=["f132d","6332569","5b55d2f","81f1330"]`

Now i dont know how to put these id into my request body. Please assist

Answer (score 1):

You can generate required request body as follows:

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the request which body you want to make dynamic
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def ids = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('id'))
   def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
   builder(Properties:[ [type: "iPhone", ids: ids.collect {[id: it,"Guid_id": null]}]])
   sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
   sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('',builder.toPrettyString(),'')
   sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true);
   ```

More information:

- [JsonBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html)
- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Appreciate your help, I tried but JSR223 file is not called by Jmeter.

Comment: Is it possible to add Loop in HTTP Request Body Data.?

Comment: Do you see anything in *jmeter.log* file?

Comment: You will not see any changes in your test, however if you add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener you should be able to observe the generated request

Comment: I have came to know that JSR223 is not reading because my JSR233 is not vaild. i am making mistake in concatenation. Before Properties I have some data and after id's also i have data.

Comment: If I only copy the solution which you have mentioned it's working fine. Thanks!  but somehow I am unable to  concatenate & produce the builder

Comment: If you are not respecting the community members and paste incomplete and/or invalid JSON my expectation is that no one will be willing to help.

Comment: Oh nothing like that. I thought it would create confusion that's why I didnt pasted. i thought i should paste only required problem. I will take care from hence forward. Appologies

Comment: @DmitriT the solution posted by you is great as a proof of concept, but I don't understand where the ids are in Jmeter. In the script you use vars.get('id') to get a the value of a variable called "id", but can this variable be a list or array in Jmeter?

Comment: @DmitriT Nevermind, I found out that I can define a variable in the User Defined Variables Config element and populate it with with an array like this [1,2,3,4]. :D